# Осветлить изображение через numpy

Tags: python

Не совсем пойму как осветлить изображение через Numpy. Можете показать как это примерно должно выглядеть. В интернете не нашёл толком про это. Как затемнить изображение я понял, но хочу понять, как его осветлить.

Comment: Пример изображения в воспросизводимом виде и ваш код приведите.

Comment: А также пример желаемого результата, чтобы было понятно, что конкретно вы имеете в виду под словом «осветлить»

Comment: Приведите ваш код для затемнения изображения. Наверняка, осветление будет очень похожим.

Answer (score 2):

```
def lighting_image(img, coef):
    img = np.array(img) / 255
    img = img + img * coef
    img[img > 1] = 1
    return img

lighting_image(img, 0.5)
```

где coef - это коэффициент осветления, значение 0.5 соответствует увеличению осветления на 50%